# How to select rows from different database tables without joining them in any way and show results in the loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have two mysql tables. I want to get the data from these tables and show it in a loop. The data is totally unrelated to each other and should stay that way. I just need to show data from these two different tables in the same place.

I tried the mysqli_multi_query, but I couldn't show the results from an individual column like I can with a normal query.

For each of these two tables, I need 2 SELECT statements with two WHERE clauses. Does anyone know how to do this?

I've tried all different ways of trying to get the info from both tables and just show them in one loop. I've tried mysqli_multi_query, but don't know how to save specific column results in a variable.

```
         $sql = "SELECT *
    FROM misc
    WHERE height LIKE '$height_input'

    SELECT * 
    FROM bolts
    WHERE name LIKE '$bolt_name_input'
    ;   
    ";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $height_row = $row['height'];
            $bolt_name_input = $row['name'];
            ?>
        Height Row: <?php echo $height_row; ?>m<br />
        bolt Name: <?php echo $bolt_name_input; ?><br /> 
        } //while
```

My error message is generally "Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object".

Comment: You really need to use two separate queries and iterate over them independently.

Comment: Technically you CAN have 2 SELECT statements in the same round trip to the database as long as they are separated by a ';'.  See [multiple row sets](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php).

Comment: @Wendy You need to provide more information about how you are trying to output the data.  If these are unrelated tables, as in the rows of table misc are complacently unrelated to bolts, you need two loops. Currently, your loop assumes that there is a 1:1 relationship between the two tables, and that relationship is the total results from each query.  As I previously mentioned, you can separate your queries with a ';' and then use `PDOStatement::nextRowset` between the two loops, but you will still need two loops which will effect how / where data is output.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Yes everyone, I have taught myself PHP and MySQL through online tutorials and have not had a lot of experience with them yet. I apologise, I am still getting the hang of this.

I have just worked out now by trial and error that I can show information from a table outside of the while loop. I had no idea I could do this! Which changes everything. So I can select information from various database tables using different SELECT statements and then echo them all into one place in my HTML table underneath it on my web page. The results don't have to be shown in the while loop, they can be outside it.

So my structure now looks like this basically:

```
SELECT from table 1 column 1 WHERE (form input value)
num rows
 while loop
  $height = $row_height['height'];
 end num rows
end while loop

SELECT from table 2 column 1 WHERE (form input value)
num rows
 while loop
  $bolts = $row_bolts['bolts'];
 end num rows
end while loop




<table>
 <tr>
  <td>echo $height</td>
  <td>echo $bolts</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

So, this is working for me to retrieve multiple results from my different tables. I have to change the variable names of the sql statement each time, I guess I could do it with a function so i can repeat it and make it look neater, but this is working for me this way. So, with bolts I am using the variable names $sql_bolts, $result_bolts and $row_bolts and with height I am using variable names $sql_height, $result_height and $row_height and so on.

```
$bolts_input = $_POST['bolts'];

        $sql_bolts = "
        SELECT *
        FROM bolts
        WHERE name LIKE '$bolts_input'
        ;";

        $result_bolts = $conn->query($sql_bolts);

        if ($result_bolts->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row_bolts = $result_bolts->fetch_assoc()) {
                $bolts = $row_bolts['name'];
         } //bolts while
        } // bolts num rows
```

I am not using mysql, but mysqli. I did a whole bunch of tutorials on PDO and how to connect to the database and retrieve information and just couldn't figure out how to show values from a row like I can with the above. It's frustrating because I want to use the latest methods, but I can't find how to online that makes sense to me.

Thank you for eveyone's comments so far.